# Why does the Selenium IDE import .* and .SpecificType?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

When you export a Selenium IDE test to Java, the code imports a *ton* of packages. Why does it automatically put in the code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

This was on a *very* basic test that I exported from the IDE to Java. Why automatically include specific packages like `selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver` and `selenium.support.ui.Select` if you're going to import the whole `selenium.*` package anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to know about java imports. Asterisk, i.e. * will import all the TYPES, i.e classes, interfaces etc in the package which precedes it, i.e. selenium. It does NOT get all the types in its sub-packages. Refer - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Now you know why this code won't compile.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```